# Display department in textbox2 to corresponding employee in textbox1 in servlet & jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am stuck in a project in jsp itself. This is a servlet & jsp project.
I have to display two text boxes in jsp page where one text box contains employee name & on the movement to 2nd text box (by `onblur()` of javascript)) his corresponding department should be displayed automatically. There are 2 tables named `emp(emp_id,emp_name,dept_id(as foreign key))` and table `dept(dept_id,dept_name)`. In 2nd text box dept_name should come automatically.

Help is appreciable. Thanking you.

Comment: If two employees have same name but their departments are different then how can you search only using name , I mean you should be able to know the `emp_id` in order to get the right employee.

Answer (score 0):

On `onblur` event write one function, use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to call the servlet and pass the name of employee.
In servlet query the database and return the response back, display the response in the second textfield.

### See also

- [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4112686/1031945)